# Uplaod .apk to fabric via curl over proxy

Tags: jenkins, proxy, google-fabric, fabric-beta

We are trying to upload .apk file generated from a pipeline in Jenkins to fabric via freestyle job through command line over a proxy server which has authentication.

We have also tried Fabric beta publisher which is not helping via a proxy which has got authentication

Please suggest